# How to remove # from url in AngularJS using Express framework?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have a website which has a front-end and back-end.
I have stored my front-end files in client folder, and back-end files in admin folder. I have removed # tag from front-end URL by adding

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

in my client app.js file and

```
<base href="/">
```

added in client index.html file

Same thing I added in admin folder file also in index.html I added

```
<base href="/admin">
```

but still, it's not working.

Here is my server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var path = require('path');

var session = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/edb');

app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next()
  });

app.use(session({secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }, resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }))


app.use('/', express.static('app', { redirect: false }));


app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'));
});
```

I have tried adding this to the server.js file

```
app.get('/admin', function (req, res, next) {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('admin/index.html'));
    });
```

but it's taking to client index.html file.

Do you have a solution?

Comment: any solution yet ?

Comment: yes I got a solution

Comment: you have to put  <base href="/"> at the top next to head open tag

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'));
});

app.get('/admin/*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('admin/index.html'));
});
```

I added this code in server.js file

its work like a charm

Comment: What if we reload the url like example.com/admin/someotherroute, it throws error