# Get request is not working after changing html5Mode(true). Need an help in express node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a MEAN stack project.
In my project, I have an admin and client module.

Here is my folder structure:

```
 - admin
    - templates
    - controller
    - app.js
 - client
    - templates
    - controller
    - app.js
 - server.js
```

For removing # tag from url I have added html5mode true and the following code in server.js file:

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'));
});

app.get('/admin/*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('admin/index.html'));
});
```

Here is my server.js file:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var app = express();

    var path = require('path');

    var session = require('express-session');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/edb');

    app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
        next()
      });

    app.use(session({secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }, resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }))


    app.use('/', express.static('app', { redirect: false }));


app.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'));
});

app.get('/admin/*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('admin/index.html'));
});
app.get('/api/enquiry', function(req, res)
{
    console.log("hai");
    dbenq.find(function(err, enquiry){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(enquiry);
    });
});
```

I am trying to get `/api/enquiry` but it not calling. It's going to

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'));
});
```

Please help to find out the solution.

Comment: try changing order of route defined . Write app.get('/*' ) in last

Comment: thank you so  much

Answer (score 0):

Change the **/*** to **/** then try, its working to me.

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'));
});
```

to

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: the '/*' I have added because after changing htmlmode5 true. refreshing the page will show error. So that's why i add the code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451178/how-to-remove-from-url-in-angularjs-usinfg-express-framework refer this question